# хранение данных в chrome extension

Tags: база-данных, chrome-extension

Подскажите пожалуйста нормально хранилище данных, больших данных в расширении гугла. Знаю есть chrome.storage - сейчас храню в нем все - пара ключь значение. Но делать выборку и т.д. не удобно от слова совсем, есть вероятность что данные потеряются и т.д.

Знаю есть WebSql, но он объявлен deprecated. Может есть еще варианты? окромя отдельного сервера который будет хранить все данные в бд mysql.

Comment: Чисто для информации. Дайте ссылку на материал про indexedDb deprecated. Не смог найти об этом информации

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft не устаревший он. моя ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

При работе с Chrome Extensions вам действительно доступен ряд решений:

1. **localStorage**
2. **chrome.storage**
3. **IndexedDB**
4. **Web SQL** [[deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/web-sql)]

Большинству разработчиков хватает возможностей **chrome.storage.local**. Лимит что-то около ~5мб (5242880 байт).

IndexedDB тоже хороший вариант. Для него есть ряд удобных библиотек. В своем проекте использую много лет, совместно с хоть и старой, но удобной [db.js](https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js/). И насколько мне известно IndexedDB не является устаревшей.

Однако, если вам действительно требуется больше возможностей от базы данных: минимальная обработка данных, хранение сложных структур и файлов – я бы порекомендовал [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/). Даже на бесплатном тарифе у них достаточно неплохие лимиты для масштабирования приложения.